# Why set-window-dedicated-p doesn't work with certain buffers?

Tags: buffers, window-splitting

I use emacs for latex,  with pdf-tools.  My layout is always  a window with PDFView buffer on the right, any other buffer on the left.

I always want the right window that cannot be touched by anything, so I have a command `anchor-buffer`

```lisp
;; custom function 'anchor-buffer'
(defun anchor-buffer ()
   "Anchor the current buffer to the current window."
   (interactive)
   (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t))
```

that doesn't allow to modify a window.  Consider the following case

- I have two windows (vertical split): 
  Left window:   tex source file, 
  Right window:  pdf file, pdf-view-mode (using pdf-tools)
- I select the pdf buffer (on the right), and I do `M-x anchor-buffer`. According to the function above this should "glue" the buffer in the right window. At least my `anchor-buffer` function works like this in all situations I tried.
- Now suppose I want to search for a reference using RefTex on the tex source (left window), and I do `C-c )`. A selection buffer opens in the right window which replaces the pdf viewer.

The latter should not happen because I invoked `set-window-dedicated-p` on right window.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you add a recipe for reproducing the problem?

Comment: Dear phils, I edited my question, I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: If pdf is in the left window, and you select it, how would that "fix" the right window? The question seems unclear to me.

Comment: @phils:  `C-c C-)` is a RefTex command which is an example about how my `anchor-function` breaks. that breaks. @Drew: sorry I edited my question, you are right, thanks.

Comment: yes, C-c ), I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I replaced my `anchor-buffer` function with the `toggle-current-window-dedication` function [shared here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2903358/2720781). Basically this `toggle-current-window-dedication`, that I report for clarity here

```lisp
;; A toggle switch for set-window-dedicated-p
;; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2903358/2720781
;;
 (defun toggle-current-window-dedication ()
   (interactive)
   (let* ((window    (selected-window))
          (dedicated (window-dedicated-p window)))
     (set-window-dedicated-p window (not dedicated))
     (message "Window %sdedicated to %s"
              (if dedicated "no longer " "")
              (buffer-name))))
  (global-set-key [pause] 'toggle-current-window-dedication)
```

is supposed to do exactly what I wanted, it  worked under all conditions included the nasty case described above.

Problem solved! Thanks for helping.

Comment: That's actually confusing, because it's exactly the same arguments to `set-window-dedicated-p` as you were using previously (when dedicating).  I wouldn't expect this to deal with any edge cases that your old function couldn't cope with, so I would *guess* that the problem was caused by something else.